# How to deploy SSL certificates on Amazon Elastic Container Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

**I have a proxy server (nginx) which has the following responsibilities:**

1. proxies to different backends depending on resource requested
2. enforces rate limiting and IP blacklisting
3. handles rewrites and url transformations
4. does SSL termination, has multiple certs & keys

The problem is it's a single point of failure, that's why I'm looking into Amazon ECS to achieve high availability and scalability.

**Here's my setup:**

1. **Amazon ECS** - EC2 instances (not Fargate) using an ALB

   - ALB will be my main entry point, traffic would be HTTPS
   - Traffic will then be forwarded to the proxy server (running tasks) which will handle SSL termination
2. **Amazon ECR** - This will hold my proxy server image, updated on rule
   changes

   - so far, I've built a simple nginx service with self-signed certs for testing

**So my question is:**

What is a good approach to deploy the SSL certs & keys to the task containers?

I'm not very familiar with AWS services, but I'd prefer to use an existing AWS solution.